# unable to import ctypes module in nuke6.1v2

Tags: python, import, ctypes

as from title, if I try to import ctypes in nuke6.1v2 I get this error:

```
import ctypes
# Result: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke6.1v2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: No module named _ctypes
```

I also tryed to import it from the Python 2.6 main folder but with no luck.

However, if I try to import it in another package (softimage for example) I have no problem at all.

I have found a lot of people having the same problem, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Any idea?

Thanks